# Rewrite Rule redirects incorrectly after a new condition is added

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a .htaccess rewrite rule which forces all of our page to HTTPS.

We need to prevent one page from being redirected.

The following would be expected to work, however instead of preventing that page from redirecting, it in fact redirects it to the index of the site.

```
# Redirect all non-ssl to ssl.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/newsletter\/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```

We've checked our expected results against here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

and we get the correct results. The page redirects to the home page with a 302 redirect. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule as **very first rule** in your .htaccess:

```
# Redirect all non-ssl to ssl.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/newsletter/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```

Using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as there might be other rules before/after this rule.

Comment: This worked! I don't understand what happens to `REQUEST_URI` though. Using `REQUEST_URI` in the `RewriteCond` shouldn't have any effect on the redirect that takes place. Can you explain? Matching against the `THE_REQUEST` is ok, but I don't understand why matching against `REQUEST_URI` doesn't.

Comment: That is because value of `REQUEST_URI` changes after application of other rules but `THE_REQUEST` remains unchanged.